# C# WPF - TextBox is not showing the characters

Tags: c#, wpf

I was programming in C # WPF, I've customized the style of a text box, and now he's not sampling the characters.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="wwindow" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="textBoxx" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFBDC4D1"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" >

                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Code of TextBox:

```
 <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource textBoxx}" x:Name="fala" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="81,118,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="177" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" SelectionBrush="#FFD6DBE9" IsEnabled="True" Cursor="IBeam" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
```

Sorry if my english is bad, i'm brazilian and i've used the Google Translate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Template` does not contain any element to display `Text`. You need to add `ScrollViewer` named `PART_ContentHost`:

```
<Border CornerRadius="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
</Border>
```

[TextBox Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> **PART_ContentHost:** A visual element that can contain a FrameworkElement. The text of the TextBox is displayed in this element.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much, I am beginner in c # and had little notion of it :) Thanks for solving my question :)